# A question about printf arguments. C/C++

Tags: c++, c, pointers, matrix, printf

We have the following code fragment:

```
char tab[2][3] = {'1', '2', '\0', '3', '4', '\0'};
printf("%s\n", tab);
```

<strike>And I don't understand why we don't get an error / warning in the call to `printf`.</strike> I DO get a warning but not an error, and the program runs fine. It prints '`12`'.
`printf` is expecting an argument of type `char *`, i.e. a pointer to `char`. So if I declared `char arr[3]`, then `arr` is an address of a memory unit which contains a `char`, so if I called `printf` with it, it would decay to *pointer to char*, i.e. `char *`.
Analogously, `tab` is an address of a memory unit that contains the type *array of 3 char's* which is in turn, an address of memory unit contains `char`, so `tab` will decay to `char **`, and it should be a problem, since `printf` is expecting a `char *`.

Can someone explain this issue?

## Addendum:

The warning I get is:
`a.c:6: warning: char format, different type arg (arg 2)`

Comment: Below you say that it works, but here you state that you get "an error / warning". What do you get exactly? It's only logical that you get a warning with this error-prone code, but do you get an error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Example Source**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) {
  char tab[2][3] = {'1', '2', '\0', '3', '4', '\0'};
  printf("%s\n", tab);

  return 0;
}
```

**Compile Warning**

```
$ gcc test.c
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:5: warning: format ‘%s’ expects type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[3]’
```

**Pointers are Pointers**

The `%s` argument to `printf` indicates to the function that it will be receiving a pointer (to a string). A string, in C, is merely a series of bytes terminated by an ASCII-Z. The `tab[2][3]` variable is a pointer. Some compilers will issue a warning about the pointer mismatch. However, the code should still print out `12` because `printf`'s code traverses memory starting at the pointer it was given (printing characters as it goes) until it finds a zero byte. The 1, 2, and \0 are contiguously set in memory, starting at the address represented by the `tab` variable.

**Experiment**

As an experiment, what happens when you compile and run the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) {
  char tab[2][3] = {'1', '2', '\0', '3', '4', '\0'};
  printf("%s\n", tab[1]);

  return 0;
}
```

Don't be afraid of experimenting. See if you can come up with the answer based on what you now know. How would you reference `tab` now (in light of the experiment) to get rid of the warning and still display `12`?

Comment: This is easy. It is the right way of calling printf. tab[1] is of type char[], and it is the same as calling printf with char *. So everything is optimal.

Comment: Exactly. So to display "12", you would use tab[0].

Answer (score 4):

The tab parameter matches the elipsis in the printf() call. C and C++ compilers are undfer no obligation to check such parameters.

Answer (score 4):

Your assumption that `tab` will decay to `char **` is wrong: `tab` has type `char [2][3]`, ie it will decay to `char (*) [3]`. It's important to understand that although arrays and pointers often behave alike, they are not the same thing. `printf()` expects a `char *`, so it takes the bits of the `char (*) [3]` and interprets them accordingly. Although it works on your platform, the C standard doesn't guarantee this: both pointers reference the same memory location, but their representation need not be identical.

Check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496226/semantics-of-char-a/496381#496381) to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496226/semantics-of-char-a) for details.

Comment: +1, I knew it was already answered somewhere, but I didn't find the question. Only thing similar I found is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232303/so-you-think-you-know-pointers

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have explained it yourself, I don't see what's left to say.

`tab` is an array of two `char *`'s. Each element of `tab` is a string that `printf` can accept, but `tab` itself is not acceptable, since it is a pointer to a pointer to a char.

Comment: tab and tab[0] point to the same location (the "12" string), so they both work, despite the mismatch.

Comment: Your problem seems to be that the compiler accepts the code.  See Neil Butterworth's answer for why this is so.  Frankly, I'm surprised the compiler is aware of the semantics of printf() and is doing any kind of type checking on its arguments.