# Different output every time in c?

Tags: c, printf, format-specifiers

I am trying to learn C and am very confused already.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a = 50000;
    float b = 'a';
    printf("b = %f\n", 'a');
    printf("a = %f\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

The above code produces a different output each time with `gcc`. Why?

Comment: In the first `printf` statement, you tried to print a `char` as a `float`. That might be part of the cause.

Comment: Using mismatching format and argument type is *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Take your compiler's warnings serious.

Comment: You should have a read about format specifiers.

Comment: Do you mean to do float     b = 'a' ? and not simply = a ?

Answer (score 2):

You pass an `int` value ('a') for a `%f` format expecting a `float` or a `double`. This is undefined behavior, which can result in different output for every execution of the same program. The second `printf` has the same problem: `%f` expects a `float` or `double` but you pass an `int` value.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a = 50000;
    float b = 'a';

    printf("a = %d\n", a);
    printf("b = %f\n", b);
    printf("'a' = %d\n", 'a');

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
a = 50000
b = 97.000000
'a' = 97
```

Compiling with more warnings enabled, with command line arguments `-Wall -W -Wextra` lets the compiler perform more consistency checks and complain about potential programming errors.  It would have detected the errors in the posted code.

Indeed `clang` still complains about the above correction:

```
clang -O2 -std=c11 -Weverything fmt.c -o fmt
fmt.c:8:24: warning: implicit conversion increases floating-point precision: 'float' to 'double' [-Wdouble-promotion]
    printf("b = %f\n", b);
    ~~~~~~             ^
1 warning generated.
```

`b` is promoted to `double` when passed to `printf()`. The `double` type has more precision than the `float` type, which might output misleading values if more decimals are requested than the original type afforded.

It is advisable to always use `double` for floating point calculations and reserve the `float` type for very specific cases where it is better suited, such as computer graphics APIs, some binary interchange formats...

Answer (score 1):

The `%f` specifier needs to be matched by a floating-point parameter (`float` or `double`), you're giving it `int`s instead. Not matching the type is undefined behaviour, meaning it could do anything, including printing different results everytime.

Hope this helped, good luck :)

Edit: Thanks chqrlie for the clarifications!

Comment: `%f` actually expects a `float` or a `double` argument. `float` arguments are promoted to `double` when passed to `printf` (and any other variadic function).  `'a'` is not a `char` in C, it is an `int` value. Btw a `char` value would be implicitly promoted to `int` when passed to `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

**Unpredictable** behavior.

When you try to print value using mismatch format specifier, compiler give an unpredictable output.The behavior on using `%f` as the format specifier for an `char` and `int` is undefined.

Use correct format specifier in your program according yo data type:

```
printf("%d\n", 'a'); // print ASCII value
printf("%d\n", a);
```

Answer (score 1):

From implementation standpoint, passing *floating point numbers* (that what `%f` expects) as variable argument lists (that is what `...` means in `printf` prototype) and *integers* (that is what `'a'` is, specifically of type `int`) may use different registers and memory layout.

This is usually defined by *ABI calling conventions*. Specifically, in x86_64, `%xmm0` will be read by printf (with unitialized value), but gcc will fill `%rdi` in `printf` call.

See more in [System V Application Binary Interface AMD64 Architecture Processor Supplement](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/article/402129/mpx-linux64-abi.pdf), p. 56

You should note that C is a very low-level language which puts a lot of confusing cases (including integer overflows and underflows, unitialized variables, buffer overruns) on shoulders of implementation. That allows to gain maximum performance (by avoiding lots of checks), but leaves to errors such as this error.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, gcc should give a warning for the above code. This is because of the mismatch in the format specifier.

Mismatched formatting (`printf()` as well as `scanf()`) will give unpredictable behavior in C. This is in spite of the fact that gcc is expected to take care possible type conversions like `int` to `float` implicitly.

Here is are two nice references.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1057173/4954434
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12830110/4954434

Following will work as expetced.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a = 50000;
    float b = 'a';
    printf("b = %f\n", (float)'a');
    printf("a = %f\n", (float)a);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main difficult you are having is the data type you are using.
When you create a variable you are telling the size the memory will have to reserve to work properly. Like `char` have a size of 1 byte, `int` equal 4 byte and `float` 32 byte. It's important to use the same data type to not have unpredictable result.

```
char a = 'a';
printf("%c",a);

int b = 50000;
printf("%d",b);

float c = 5.7;
printf("%f", c);
```

For more information: [C-Variables](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_variables.htm)